# Prerequisites for Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to self learn mathematics and I found out about Basic Mathematics. What are the prerequisites for this book? Should I read a book on mathematical proofs? I know some very basic math like arithmetic, exponents and fractions.

Comment: The prerequisites for that book are algebra and geometry.  Lang wrote *Basic Mathematics* so that students would have a solid foundation for calculus.  However, the book differs substantially from the standard pre-calculus courses offered in the United States.